Can the weight distribution of a partially supported rigid mass be determined?
Consider a rigid block of mass $M$ and length $L=L_1+L_2$ partially hanging off a table, as shown below:

If the center of mass is precisely on the ledge ($x=0$), then it's not hard to see that the normal forces exerted from the table must be entirely concentrated at the ledge itself.
Any normal force applied by the table at $x<0$ would produce a torque about the ledge that can't be balanced by any other force, since the hanging part exerts no upward force.
Suppose now the block is shifted a bit to the left, so that the center of mass is at $x_{\rm cm}<0$, inside the table region, as shown in the figure.
The system is thus at equilibrium.
The question is: how are the normal forces exerted by the table distributed along the contact region ($-L_1\le x\le 0$)?
An attempt that doesn't work
While this seems like an easy enough application of static mechanics concepts, I have trouble actually finding a way to solve this problem.
When the block is entirely on the table, the normal forces should be evenly distributed across the contact surface.
I know the solution has to be that the forces are evenly distributed when the block is entirely on the table, and I know the force has to be entirely concentrated on the ledge when the center of mass is on the ledge. But how do you solve the problem in the general case?
Let's denote the mass per unit length as $\lambda(x)$, and let $f(x)dx$ be the (upwards) normal force exerted by the table around the position $x$.
We can impose the equilibrium conditions for the rigid block:
$$\int_{-L_1}^0 dx f(x) = Mg, \\
\int_{-L_1}^0 dx \,x f(x) + g\int_{-L_1}^{L_2} dx x\lambda(x)=0.$$
The first integral represents the total normal forces, and the second equation contains the total torque of normal forces and gravity, about the ledge.
But these aren't enough to determine $x\mapsto f(x)$.
I could also write Newton's equation locally for each slice $dx$, but that would involve the internal forces required to impose rigidity, and again I don't have enough equations to solve for all the unknowns.
A simpler (solvable) discrete model: 3 balls on a rod
The continuous aspects of the problem above involve some complications that are not necessarily intrinsic to the problem itself, so we can consider as a stepping stone a simpler discrete problem instead.
Say we have 3 masses on a rigid massless rod, two resting on supports, and the other one hanging. Again, assume center of mass inside the region with supports:

In this case, I can actually solve the problem: if $f_1,f_2$ are the normal forces on the two left masses, and $L_i$ are their distances from the ledge (thus $L_2=0$) we must have
$$f_1 + f_2 = (m_1+m_2+m_3) g, \\
- f_1 L_1 + m_1 g L_1 - m_3 g L_3 = 0,$$
which easily lead to the solution:
$$
f_1 = m_1 g - m_3 g \frac{L_3}{L_1},
\qquad
f_2 = m_2 g + m_3 g\left(1 + \frac{L_3}{L_1}\right).
$$
This makes perfect sense and shows that the load on the left support is smaller than the load on the central one. And in the limit of $m_1=m_3$ and $L_1=L_3$, where the center of mass is on the center support, we get $f_1=0$, consistently with the previous reasoning.
Adding a ball already makes it hard to solve
Here's the issue, adding even just a single additional supported mass, I can't seem to get to the solution. The core reason is that if I want to avoid dealing with internal forces, my only two weapons for a rigid body are total external force and total external torque. These give me two conditions, which is not enough if there's more than two normal forces to determine:
$$f_1 + f_2 + f_3 = (m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4)g,
\\
-f_1 L_1 - f_2 L_2 + m_1 g L_1 + m_2 g L_2 - m_4 g L_4=0$$
isn't enough to get $f_1,f_2,f_3$.
On the other hand, the problem seems entirely well-determined to me: I can imagine doing this experiment, and getting the answer. And it doesn't seem like more involved physics should be needed. So what's missing? What other properties of a rigid body can be used to get to the answer? Or alternatively, is there a good way to deal with internal forces to solve the problem?
Statically indeterminate problems
As a final remark, I should mention that I did stumble upon the idea of statically indeterminate problems while thinking about this.
This problem seems a clear-cut example of such a thing: the equations aren't enough to determine the normal forces. However, I'm struggling to make physical sense of this.
Reading about statically indeterminate problems I see that one has to involve material properties, so use models more involved that just "perfectly rigid body". But at the same time, it seems physically unexpected that this is the case: if I tried to do this experiment (using scales to measure weight distribution or something), would the answer really depend that strongly on the elastic properties, even in the limit where objects are very close to being rigidly connected?
This seems even more odd if I consider instead the equivalent situation where the mass is hanging from a bunch of wires, and the question is to determine the tensions in the wires: while should material properties other than its mass distribution matter from the perspective of the wires' tensions?
Furthermore, I'm puzzled by the fact that in the limit of center of mass on the ledge, the problem is not statically indeterminate. So whatever model might be necessary in general, we must get a convergence to the same solution in this limit. Is there a way to solve the problem, using some physically plausible assumptions, that allows to see this phenomenon?

@Bob I hope this isn't given as homework to anyone lol

I was too late to help in the chat when you were discussing this question.
For any $0<L_2\leqslant L_1$ so that things are interesting, simply first consider chopping the $L_2$ part off. This way, the entire block of length $L_1$ lies in the table, so that the obvious solution is that the entire weight $L_1\frac MLg$ is uniformly distributed on the table, i.e. dividing that over the entire intact length $L_1$, the weight distribution function is $f(x)=\frac MLg=\text{const}$, and this is equal to the normal reaction force distribution function too.
Now consider the cut part $L_2$ as a point mass. Let us have a lopsided weighing scale centred on the edge be holding this point mass up. It should also be holding up the centre of mass of the uncut part $L_1$. How much can be held up? Well, by considering torques, you should be able to see that the cut part $L_2$ with weight $L_2\frac ML g$ centred at $x=+\frac{L_2}2$ will hold up, at $x=-\frac{L_1}2$ a weight equivalent to $\frac{L_2^2}{L_1}\frac ML g$; this means that in the above consideration with the uniformly distributed weight profile, we will now have this uniformly distributed weight profile be reduced to
$$\tag1\frac{L_1\dfrac MLg-\dfrac{L_2^2M}{L_1L}g}{L_1}=\frac MLg\left[1-\left(\frac{L_2}{L_1}\right)^2\right]$$
with the rest being a concentrated spike force at the edge $x=0$ as a Dirac delta distribution, i.e.
$$\tag2f(x)=\frac MLg\left[1-\left(\frac{L_2}{L_1}\right)^2\right]+\frac{L_2}L\left(1+\frac{L_2}{L_1}\right)Mg\,\delta(x)$$
You can see that, by construction, this distribution of forces satisfies that $\int_{-L_1}^{0^+}f(x)\,\mathrm dx=Mg$ and also satisfies torque balance about $x=0$, and it also has the correct limiting behaviour when $L_2\to0$ and $L_2\to L_1$. To check this solution, the smart move is to consider a pivot at $x=-\frac{L_1}2$, so that the constant term of this force distribution cancels away; the "point mass" of $L_1\frac MLg$ also cancels away, leaving just the Dirac delta distribution and the hanging "point mass" of $L_2\frac MLg$ to cancel between each other. This means that this solution is mathematically satisfactory; it cannot be satisfy force balance and torque balance at two different points and yet not also satisfy torque balance at any other pivoting point.

However, it is unphysical to have Dirac delta distributions of forces when a distribution could have worked. I mean, consider a $L_2\ll L_1\approx L$; it would be ridiculous to have the Dirac delta distribution in such a scenario. I leave it to you to consider a linear distribution of forces to achieve the same result without the Dirac delta distribution. I think it is possible, and it also is in accord with the physics; you know that when the table is replaced with sand, a box that is sinking in the sand would slant just a little and be embedded linearly into the edge. I really don't think a complicated force distribution will ever be able to satisfy both the force balance and torque balance. It should be a linear force distribution, or at most complication an odd force distribution about $x=-\frac{L_1}2$. The difficulty is that there is an additional constraint at the leftmode edge $x=-L_1$, such that the upward normal reaction force at this leftmost edge cannot dip below zero. When it dips to zero, the rest of the force appears as a Dirac delta distribution at the edge at $x=0$. If you get obtain this solution, then you should have a completely satisfactory solution, because clearly a solution of this form satisfies all the possible limiting behaviours, and is blatantly physically plausible. And that it also highlights the indeterminism: I mean, I already gave you one mathematically satisfactory solution, so any other solution implies non-uniqueness.
The reason why the Dirac delta distribution is physically unsatisfactory is that, amongst other issues, it has very strong shearing at the edge $x=0$. Instead, it is physically more sensible to have a distribution of the shearing stress across the entire block, and that is also why I strongly suspect another solution exists, that would seek to minimise this shearing stress. I mean, you can physically see a long rod bend when subjected to this. There can thus be a complicated behaviour relating the edge $x=0$ with the rest of the system.

if I understand you correctly, you're saying the mass portion over the table gets distributed equally on the support, while the weight hanging over the ledge gets concentrated on the ledge. But I'm not seeing how this can be the case: looking at the external torques, if the normal force is equally distributed on the support, it'd have a net torque (about the center of mass) that would make the object fall, no? I feel like you'd need a stronger normal force between center of mass and ledge to have equilibrium. You also see it in the case with 3 masses, where weight concentrates on the center

I have shown in no uncertain terms that the "lifted uniform distribution plus Dirac delta" satisfies the torque balance and force balance and is thus necessarily a mathematically satisfactory solution. It is not "mass portion over the table gets distributed equally". It is "mass portion minus hanging". Also, after the horizontal line I gave you an exercise to derive an even better distribution. Your 3 masses solution is actually in agreement with mine.

right, I see it now, thanks! I was neglecting the spike at the ledge computing the torque. A posteriori, I agree that this is an obvious solution to the problem. I find fascinating that it's also based on some assumptions (such as balanced distribution on the left part of the table). In other words, it's going to depend on the material whether it's the correct one or not. Sure the Dirac delta is not going to represent the true physics, but that's fine, it just means "very concentrated around that point" in my book. Now I'm really curious to try the experiment and see what I get

No, no, you should consider the exercise I left at the end. I really don't think the Dirac delta spike is tolerable until $L_2\approx L_1$; that is, if $L_2\ll L_1$, then there should be no Dirac delta spike at all.

by the "exercise" you mean essentially to find a solution using $f(x)=A+Bx$ (for $x\le 0$) as an ansatz?

Yes, with the condition that $A-L_1B>0$ so that everything is physically sensible. I vaguely remember that something like this would work, but I cannot remember the details, nor the specific reasoning why it works.
